# Creating textViews on Button click

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a UIButton in UIViewController, i want add to dynamic number of UITextViews in the ViewController on this button click action. After creating textviews i am moving it using touches, but as i create a new textview the previous textview does not respond to touch event.Why is this happening? 
 here is my code:

```
    -(IBAction)createTextView{

       UITextView *textView =[[UITextView alloc]init];
       textView.frame=CGRectMake(40,40,10,300);
       [self.view addSubview:textView];
     }
```

Comment: Your leaking memory.  You need to release the textView after you have added it to the view like this `[textView release];`.  As for the textView not responding to touch events, please post some code showing your touch method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `textView.delegate=self;` after allocating the `textView`. Hope it will work fine once its done.